# Oracle 11g express edition listener error

Tags: database, oracle, connection, listener

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br6aQ.png)I am getting listener related error when trying to connect to database using sql developer and through odbc DSN config testing saying "ORA-12505" TNS listener doesn't currently know of the SID given in connect descriptor... please help me i have to reinstall every time this error shows which every 3 days it has become a hassle for me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iitei.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJC03.png)

Comment: Is everything happening on a single machine?  Or separate machines?  Are you using local naming?  If so, what is your tnsnames.ora file?  What is your listener.ora file?  Is the listener running?  My wild guess if something breaks every 3 days is that your listener.ora is telling the listener to run on a fixed IP address when your machine gets a dynamic IP address that changes every few days (or that your tnsnames.ora file is telling the client to connect to a fixed IP address).

Comment: Reinstalling for this is like tearing your house down and rebuilding just because the front door is stuck. I have to disagree with @JustinCave. If it were an IP address issue, you would get a different error.  The error you get means that the request did successfully reach the listener before being rejectd _by_ the listener.  You need to update your question to show _formatted_ output of 'lsnrctl status.  Also, you mention both SQL Dev and ODBC.  Let's focus just on SQL Dev for the moment (doesn't need ODBC).  Show a screen shot of your connection config.

Comment: I have added screenshots of .ora files and config files as links in my post could you please check them